# QGIS - how to split features based on overlap

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, splitting

**Splitting by overlap**

I need to find a way to split features based on overlap within the same layer. If, for example, I have two circles that overlap partially, I would have an output of three features (ideally with the number of overlaps - that would be 1 or 0 for the parts with no overlap and 1 or 2 for the middle overlapping part - I wrote 0 or 1 and 1 or 2 because it does not batter if it counts the number of overlaps or the number of features that overlap).

**Figure 1: Basic principle**
[image: Visualised basic principle of overlap]

Real example: I have isochrones of walking distances and I want to differentiate areas with more that one isochrone overlapping. One way to do this is to create a fine grid where I use `Join attributes by location (summary)`, but that is more steps and more computational power, that I would like to avoid. Ideally I would also like to add some values to this overlap - for example if one isochrone has potential 5 customers and the other has 10, I would like to have 15 customers in the overlapping part. I need this for around 900 features, so this cannot be done by hand.

**To sum up:**

- How can I split features based on overlap?
- How can I add values that are the sum of a selected attributes for all overlapping features?

Comment: Try the ["Union"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union) tool, also check these: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/summing-up-values-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424037/creating-duplicate-points-as-many-times-as-it-overlap-with-polygons-in-qgis

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392905/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418527/88814